# Save Room Reservation Using AngularJS, Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Scenario:

A **Reservation** is booked by a user for a specific room. A reservation entity has these properties:

```
private Long reservationId;
private Date startTime;
private Date endTime;
private User user;
private Room room;
private String note;
```

As you can see, the reservation entity takes in a User and Room entity as well. **I am attempting to save this reservation into the database** but keep running into the following upon saving:

```
HTTP Status 400 -description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

I think my problem has to do with incorrectly passing the User and Room objects, but I'm not quite at the point yet where I can figure out exactly what the problem is.

This is my Spring @RestController method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ReservationResource> addReservation(@RequestBody ReservationResource reservation){
    try{
        Reservation newReservation = reservationService.addReservation(reservation.toReservation());
        ReservationResource reservationResource = new ReservationResourceAsm().toResource(newReservation);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(URI.create(reservationResource.getLink("self").getHref()));
        return new ResponseEntity<ReservationResource>(reservationResource, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (ReservationExistsException exception) {
        throw new ConflictException(exception); 
    }
}
```

This is my Angular controller:

```
.controller('AddReservationController', function($scope, $state, $http, reservationService){
    $scope.reservation = {};

    $http.get("/libroomreserve/api/user/1").then(
        function(resource){
            console.log(resource);
            $scope.reservation.user = resource.data;
        },
        function(){
            $scope.reservation.user = null;
        }
    );
    $http.get("/libroomreserve/api/room/1").then(
        function(resource){
            $scope.reservation.room = resource.data;
        },
        function(){
            $scope.reservation.room = null;
        }
    );

    $scope.newReservation = function(){
    reservationService.addReservation(
        $scope.reservation,
        function(data){
            console.log("Success! Data printing:");
            console.log(data);
            $state.go("home");
        },
        function(data){
            console.log("Failure! Data printing:");
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
};
});
```

and the corresponding Angular factory service:

```
.factory('reservationService', function($resource){
var reservations = {};

reservations.addReservation = function(reservation, success, failure){
    var Reservation = $resource('/libroomreserve/api/reservation');
    Reservation.save({}, reservation, success, failure);
};

return reservations;
})
```

Finally, here is the Request payload, whose content I ran through a validator and it checked out:

```
{"user":{"userId":1,"userName":"tom","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost:8080/libroomreserve/api/user/1"}]},"room":{"roomId":1,"roomNumber":"101A","roomDescription":"Best room ever","roomCapacity":15,"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost:8080/libroomreserve/api/room/1"}]},"startTime":"2015-12-25 00:00:00","endTime":"2015-12-25 00:00:00","note":"dsfds"}
```

UPDATE

Here is a mess of errors returned by log4j when POSTing a reservation. **Seems to be an issue with the start and end dates being passed.**

```
    DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/libroomreserve/api/reservation]
Looking up handler method for path /api/reservation
Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource> com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.controllers.ReservationController.addReservation(com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource)]
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reservationController'
Skip CORS processing, request is a same-origin one
Read [class com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@ec39299]
Error resolving argument [0] [type=com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.controllers.ReservationController]
Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource> com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.controllers.ReservationController.addReservation(com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource)]

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:224)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:55)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:904)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:787)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateBasedDeserializer._parseDate(DateDeserializers.java:175)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:261)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:337)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:131)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3731)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2808)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:221)
    ... 76 more
Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource> com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.controllers.ReservationController.addReservation(com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"])
Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource> com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.controllers.ReservationController.addReservation(com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"])
Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource> com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.controllers.ReservationController.addReservation(com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"])
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"])
SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': Can not parse date "2015-12-25 00:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f05a63c; line: 1, column: 295] (through reference chain: com.ucrisko.libroomreserve.rest.resources.ReservationResource["startTime"])
Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
Successfully completed request
Chain processed normally
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Crank up your logs to `DEBUG` and see exactly what problem it's having with the mapping.

Comment: Unless I'm doing it wrong the logs have been set to DEBUG but there are no errors showing. I'm thinking maybe the request doesn't even make it to my RestController because if it did it should trip the catch block of my POST method and trigger a 409 Conflict error.

Comment: Right; the problem is with the data binding. If you turn up `org.springframework.web`, it'll describe the entire resolution and binding process.

Comment: In my application.properties file I have a property: 

logging.level.org.springframework.web = DEBUG

This is what I need, correct?

Comment: Unless you have a more comprehensive logging configuration, then yes, that'll configure the basic Boot log setup. You should be seeing a lot of messages from the DispatcherServlet when you make the request.

Comment: That was the problem: I didn't have my log4j.properties file configured correctly. Now I am seeing error messages which I will post above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is very specific:

```
Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-12-25 00:00:00': not a valid representation
```

By default, Jackson tries to map dates to ISO-8601:

```
standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

You'll need to annotate the property in question to tell Jackson what format to use. Something like this should work:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: There were a couple other issues with code not listed here but this was the biggest issue. Solving this one helped get the ball rolling. Much appreciated!